# RACObserve subscribeNext performSelector:afterDelay: not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm using ReactiveCocoa 2.5 because I need to support iOS 7. I'm new at ReactiveCocoa. I have this code:

```
   __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
   [RACObserve(_currentUser, username) subscribeNext:^(NSString *newUsername) {
        [weakSelf performSelector:@selector(saveUserChanges) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
   }];
```

First time when code reaches `performSelector` everything works just fine and `saveUserChanges` method get called after delay. But then the code reaches the same `performSelector` line many times but `saveUserChanges` method never get called again. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Ensure that `weakSelf` is not `nil` in the body of the block -- that would explain what you're observing.

Comment: Yes, I've checked it. It's not `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your weakSelf was released. Make sure the weakSelf is not nil in the block.

When you use weak object in block, it's better to strong it again like this:

```
@weakify(self);
[RACObserve(_currentUser, username) subscribeNext:^(NSString *newUsername) {
    @strongify(self);
    [self performSelector:@selector(saveUserChanges) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
}];
```

Comment: @tagirkaZ Did you verify if the weakSelf is nil? Another question is: How many times did you call this selector?

Comment: yes, I've checked that it's not nil. Actually `[self saveUserChanges]` works as expected. I call this selector only in `subscribeNext` block. So it called once per `subscribeNext`. I cause `username` property changing by myself with some UI actions.

Comment: performSelector:withObject:afterDelay will create a NSTimer in NSDefaultRunLoopMode to perform the selector in current thread. I don't know why you meet this issue. Do you change username property in main thread always?

Comment: You are absolutely right! It was changed in the main thread only first time. Next calls was in another thread. That's why it worked only first time. I changed `performSelector` to `performSelectorOnMainThread` and everything works now. Thanks a lot!